# Проектирование базы данных: как хранить напряжение ламп?

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

В базе данных хранится информация о лампах. У большинства ламп указано номинальное напряжение, однако у некоторых - допустимый диапазон.

Каким образом лучше хранить в БД информацию о напряжении и почему?

На вскидку варианты:

- Два поля типа **decimal** (*v_min, v_max*). Если указано номинальное напряжение, то либо хранить одинаковые значения в обоих полях, либо оставить одно из полей пустым.
- Два поля типа **decimal**. Первое под номинальное напряжение, в которое также пишется среднее напряжение, если есть диапазон. Второе - под *(max-min)/2* (со значением *null* по умолчанию).
- Одно поле типа **varchar**, в котором хранить либо одну цифру, либо диапазон
- Создать две дочерние таблицы - одну под номинальное напряжение, другую - под диапазон.

Еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: table (id int, min int not null, max int null)

Comment: Хранить одинаковые значения и просто интерпретировать номинальное как диапазон, чтобы не работать с двумя сущностями разом. Но если это какой-то магазин, то, конечно, подход не очень верен.

Comment: _"и почему?"_ -- представьте что в базе 1 миллиард записей. и надо выбрать лампы у которых указан диапазон, и вернуть sum (max - min). если поле varchar, то надо будет строки переводить в числа.

Comment: Не совсем понятно какие запросы (фильтры) вы собираетесь делать по этим значениям. Если никаких, то есть данные чисто справочные, то можно хранить хоть картинкой в блобе. Вот за вас уже придумали суммировать разницу границ, что, выглядит как пятое колесо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table (id int, 
       min int not null,  -- номинальное напряжение
       max int null       -- максимальное напряжение
      )
```

Почему так? Представьте, что в таблице 1 миллиард записей и надо выбрать лампы, которые могут работать с определенным напряжением и вернуть sum (max - min). Если данные хранить в поле типа varchar, то строки при запросе надо будет преобразовывать в числа.